# Incrementing aggregate the hudi table value using spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, apache-hudi

I have a spark streaming job that loads the data in `apache hudi` table every 10 seconds. It update the row in hudi table if the row already exists. Actually, it is doing an upsert operation.

But in hudi table, there is an amount column that is also updated with the new value.

```
for example
 1 batch, id=1, amount value=10. --> in table, amount value = 10
 2 batch, id=1, amount value=20. --> in table, amount value = 20
```

But I need the amount value should `30` not `20`. I need to incrementally aggregate the amount column.

Does hudi support incremental aggregation usecase without using external caching/db?

Comment: Don't know about Hudi maybe with a spark watermark (Stateful Incremental Execution)https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#window-operations-on-event-time

Answer (score 0):

Apache Hudi uses the class `org.apache.hudi.common.model.OverwriteWithLatestAvroPayload` by default to precombine your dataframe records and upsert old stored records, which simply checks if your dataframe contains duplicated records with the same key, and choose the records which have the max `ordering` field, then replace the old stored records with the new ones coming selected from your inserted data.

But you can create your own record payload class by implementing the interface `org.apache.hudi.common.model.HoodieRecordPayload`, and setting the config `hoodie.compaction.payload.class` to your class. ([Here](https://hudi.apache.org/docs/configurations/#RECORD_PAYLOAD) is more configs)